# Android studio can't connect through ADB on OSX

Tags: android, macos, ide, android-studio

I've been working a bit with Android Studio on OSX 10.7.5 and it looks very promising. I've run into a problem when trying to launch an application on my device however.

When clicking the run button, AS claims to be "waiting for ADB". After a while it times out and says that "ADB is not responding...".

I've tried rebooting and restarting adb with `adb-killserver` and `adb-startserver` many times but it won't connect. When running `adb devices` or launching through eclipse, all works fine.

Anyone got ideas, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Just FWIW, for 5/2014, it now seems to work pretty reliably.  (If you're in the El33t "Mac-AndroidStudio" group :), note this question for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559554/is-android-studio-v0-5-2-on-mac-usable-now-for-production-apps )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT: This actually solved my issue so this is the accepted answer. It seems [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26491179/1068167) also helps alot of people but it did not work for me.**

Here's what I did to finally make it work. No idea which of these steps triggered my working copy as it seemed very random but I will put them in order.

1. Uninstall AS
2. Remove old path to adb from bash
3. Turn off firewall (or at least monitor which connections are being made by AS and various USB drivers and allow them)
4. Install AS
5. Change target device under Run -> Edit configurations
6. Launch
7. It works...maybe!
   ...
   ...
8. Change theme
9. Reboot
10. Doesn't work
11. Unplug and plug in device
12. Should work, if not try rebooting and unplugging/plugging until it does.

Comment: Funny to get downvotes on the answer that actually solved the issue.

Answer (score 11):

On the OS X the following steps solved my problem:

1. Disconnect your Android devices;
2. Quit Android Studio;
3. Force Quit process 'adb' from the Activity Monitor;
4. Start Android Studio.

Comment: In my mac system there are more than one ADB running. It's getting recreated even after Force quit. Any idea?

Comment: I had a weird variation of this issue (also on Mac OS). Killing the ADB deamon and restarting Android Studio didn't help at all. When I inspected the "Event Log" pane in Android studio, I realised that Android Studio was attempting to connect to ADB on a host different from my local machine. Disabling WI-FI and killing / restarting the ADB deamon and Android Studio, while the network adapter was disconnected, finally fixed the issue for my part.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem with Android Studio 0.5.3. I would recommend restarting your computer, if the adb kill-server, adb start-server method doesn't work.

Comment: Your answer would be a lot more useful for others if you can explain why that'll help.

Comment: I guess android studio is just buggy... Anyway, just restarting worked for me. Thanks ;)

Comment: This does not workes for me on Mac - 12.1

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem when I using the genymotion. At last, I realized the problem is that the adb location is not the same as the android studio. So you should update the adb of your genymotion.
The step: Genymotion settings -> ADB -> Use custom Android SDK tools

[image: The setting image]

Comment: This was my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just had this happen on my Mac Mini and it ended up working (recognizing the Nexus 5) when I plugged the cable into a different USB port on the back...

Answer (score 1):

In order to get my application running on a device, I needed to edit the run configuration for the app by going into the **Run** menu and selecting **Edit Configurations**.

I selected the configuration that had my app's name and changed the **Target Device** to **USB Device** which then allowed me to run the app from a device. Beforehand I was getting similar behavior to what you describe. It is possible yours is an entirely different issue :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing happen. As soon as I unplugged my device, the "Waiting for ADB" notification disappeared and it worked. I guess you can't start AS when a device is plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

Span said that you should do strange things, but sometimes it works (strange = reinstall, reboot using word 'maybe'). We should understand that it could be, because of some bad settings in OS which had been changed, but you do not remember about it.

But my case was even stranger! :)

Cause Windows do not limit you to have many Firewalls it could be the key! Firewalls might not permit some apps to connect withother, you should check also it.

I described it in:
[here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=170726)

Assuming the crash course to start Android Studio:

- disable connection to internet (for security),
- uninstall Android Studio,
- remove .gradle and .AndroidStudio folder from your home directory,
- remove all firewalls right way, reinstall & set them up to allow,
- remove all av's the same as above,
- check Windows internal firewall (or iptables in Linux :) ),
- install Android Studio.

If it do not work and you want to have your OS not reinstalled - make VM with Windows and try. If not work - reinstall system :(

Regards.