# AndroidStudio gradle proxy

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I've tried to run [`AndroidStudio`](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)
But It's failing on boot with `gradle` error:

`Failed to import Gradle project: Connection timed out: connect`

I found solution [**here**](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3aaccessing_the_web_via_a_proxy)

But I can't find how to set this properties in `Android Studio`.

Setting them in `graddle-wrapper.properties` doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried passing them as VM options? In Android Studio -> Preferences -> Gradle, pass the proxy details as VM options -Dhttp.proxyHost=www.somehost.org -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 etc.

Comment: I described method to get it working here, on Stack: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33690567/2672951

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In Android Studio -> Preferences -> Gradle, pass the proxy details as VM options.

Gradle VM Options
`-Dhttp.proxyHost=www.somehost.org -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080` etc.

*In 0.8.6 Beta Gradle is under File->Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S, on Windows and Linux)

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. Full settins structure valid for me (with user and password if someone looking for this): `-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.domain.company.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8090 -Dhttp.proxyUser=atiris -Dhttp.proxyPassword=mysecretpassword`

Comment: @Rajesh how to pass if it is a pac file

Comment: @codebased, AFAIK, there is no way to provide Proxy Auto-Configuration script directly to the VM. You may open the file and figure out the actual proxy to use in case of internet access and provide the same to Gradle as explained above.

Comment: For Android Studio 1.3.2+ look at @sumit-sahoo 's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26840246/2657607

Comment: @Rajesh where is 'Preferences' in Android studio, I'm unable to find it in Android Studio version 2.0

Answer (score 91):

Go to `gradle.properties` file (project root directory) and add these options.

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=user
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost
systemProp.http.auth.ntlm.domain=domain

systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=user
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost
systemProp.https.auth.ntlm.domain=domain
```

Comment: I had problems downloading gradle 1.0.0-rc1 pom file - this helped. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks this helped. I looked in all the places except the project directory.. Duh!

Comment: I'm using this snippet of code, but yet still I'm facing issues in sync with Gradle

Comment: i have android studio1.5, and do this but its error has still  yet. what can i do?

Comment: what should i add in www.somehost.org. i dont know my proxy host?

Comment: My companies proxy is in the format `https://host.blabla.net`. I  tried many settings until I noticed when I did an echo of my systems proxies in Linux, that it returned `https://https://host.blabla.net`. Apparently I should have just written `host.net`, without `https://` in front of it. Changing this in the gradle.properties fixed my problem of not being able to get any repositories (while being at the office).

Comment: Fix my problem:`Could not download xxx.aar(xxx.jar)`

Answer (score 22):

For Android Studio 3.2(Windows),you can edit the `gradle.properties` file under `C:/Users/USERNAME/.gradle` for current user.

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euOKX.png)

Answer (score 8):

in gradle.properties file (project root directory)

You must set proxy for http and https

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=user
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost
systemProp.http.auth.ntlm.domain=domain

systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=user
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost
systemProp.https.auth.ntlm.domain=domain
```

if you set proxy from File -> Settings ->HTTP Proxy(Under IDE Settings)
it only define http proxy and does not set https proxy

Answer (score 7):

For an NTLM Authentication Proxy:

File -> Settings -> Project Settings -> Gradle -> Global Gradle Settings -> Gradle VM Options

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=myProxyAddr -Dhttp.proxyPort=myProxyPort -Dhttp.proxyUser=myUsername -Dhttp.proxyPassword=myPasswd -Dhttp.auth.ntlm.domain=myDomainName
```

Comment: There is no Gradle VM Options in Android studio 1.3.2

Answer (score 5):

Rajesh's suggestion did not work for me. What I did was go to

File -> Settings ->HTTP Proxy(Under IDE Settings) ->Manual proxy configuration

I still left the proxy information in Project Settings under Gradle, like Rajesh suggested. But I'm not entirely sure if it's necessary.

I am using 0.8.6 Beta

Answer (score 5):

In my case I am behind a proxy with dynamic settings.
I had to download the settings script by picking the script address from internet settings at
 `Chrome > Settings > Show Advanced Settings > Change proxy Settings > Internet Properties > Connections > LAN Settings > Use automatic configuration script > Address`
Opening this URL in a browser downloads a PAC file which I opened in a text editor

- Look for a `PROXY` string, it should contain a hostname and port
- Copy values into `gradle.properties`

`systemProp.https.proxyHost=blabla.domain.com`
`systemProp.https.proxyPort=8081`

- I didn't have to specify a user not password.

Answer (score 4):

For Android Studio 1.4, I had to do the following ...

In the project explorer window, open the "Gradle Scripts" folder.

Edit the gradle.properties file.

Append the following to the bottom, replacing the below values with your own where appropriate ...

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=?.?.?.?
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
# Next line in form DOMAIN/USERNAME for NTLM or just USERNAME for non-NTLM
systemProp.http.proxyUser=DOMAIN/USERNAME
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=PASSWORD
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost
# Next line is required for NTLM auth only
systemProp.http.auth.ntlm.domain=DOMAIN

systemProp.https.proxyHost=?.?.?.?
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
# Next line in form DOMAIN/USERNAME for NTLM or just USERNAME for non-NTLM
systemProp.https.proxyUser=DOMAIN/USERNAME
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=PASSWORD
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost
# Next line is required for NTLM auth only
systemProp.https.auth.ntlm.domain=DOMAIN
```

Details of what gradle properties you can set are here...
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3aaccessing_the_web_via_a_proxy

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me .
File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy
Put in your proxy setting in Manual proxy configuration

Restart android studio, a prompt pops up and asks you to add the proxy setting to gradle, click yes.

Answer (score 1):

For the new android studio 1.2 you find the gradle vm args under:

```
File
- Settings
  - Build, Execution, Deployment
    - Build Tools
      - Gradle
```

Comment: `- Build Tools
     -Compiler`
In latest Android Studio 1.3.2

Answer (score 1):

If you are at the office and behind the company proxy, try to imports all company proxy cacert into `jre\lib\security` because gradle uses jre's certificates.

Plus, config your gradle.properties. It should work

More details go to that thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/kdP2iNgcQFM/BDY7H0os18oJ

Comment: This prevents Android Studio from upgrading to newer versions because that change will be seen as a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

If build failed due to gradle proxy setting then simply putting my proxy IP address and port number will solve. It worked for me.
File -> setting -> http proxy -> manual configuration -> Host name: your proxy IP, port number: your proxy port number.

Answer (score 1):

If you have checked the **proxy settings** in your Android Studio and in the **gradle.properties** in the root directory of your project, you may need to check the .gradle in the home directory of your system and it worked for me:

**Linux:**

> ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

**Windows:**

> C:/Users/USERNAME/.gradle/gradle.properties

If you find these lines, remote them:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=localhost
systemProp.https.proxyHost=localhost
systemProp.https.proxyPort=40875
systemProp.http.proxyPort=40875
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the below mentioned settings in build.gradle(:app)
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
targetSdkVersion 30

(Only if build is failing then follow the below mentioned steps)
Then go to proxy setting, You can find it under settings, select manual proxy settings, HostName : Ip address and port number you can find by using command netstat-a in CMD. First it will show tcp and after sometime it will start showing port number(UDP)

Answer (score 0):

edit the **gradle.properties** like below

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DsocksProxyPort=10810
```

or

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DsocksProxyPort=10810
```

this is worked for me, and I used V2Ray