# android studio can't build project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After removing the old android studio, I install a new one, (Beta)0.8.6. Build number:AI-135.1339820.
When I try to build my project, it can't be built, the following is log:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'Game'.
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2.
>        Required by:
>            :Game:unspecified
>   Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.12.2/gradle-0.12.2.pom'.
>   Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused

Game is my project's name. I have struggled this problem with hours, but without any progress.

Comment: change the 12 to 11. and try for build once.

Comment: After I did it, it said the minimum supported version is 0.12.0.

Comment: @Nava2011  Android Studio 0.8.x requires gradle-plugin 0.12.+
Check you internet connection

Answer (score 4):

It should be related to proxy settings.

Check following link to set proxy in android studio.
[AndroidStudio gradle proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443208/androidstudio-gradle-proxy)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Antivirus/Internet security and if you are using Windows then windows firewall. Try rebuilding the project. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure your proxy support https. If not you can force [Android Studio to fetch dependencies and AS updates using HTTP instead of HTTPS](http://www.error.report/2016/02/android-studio-failure-build-failed.html) (where available).