# Gradle "MyApplication4" project refresh failed Error: Connection refused: connect

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Good day!! I'm new to android development... I've successfully started my Android Development Studio, downloaded the necessary SDKs via sdk manager, and created a project. I'm following a tutorial where it says that I should be able to run my project (Blank Activity) after setting up a virtual device. Problem is I was able to run the virtual device but I cannot run my project. I kept on receiving the error: *Gradle "MyApplication4" project refresh failed Error: Connection refused: connect* i've tried using the solution provided here ([AndroidStudio gradle proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443208/androidstudio-gradle-proxy)) but issue still occurs:

I went to File >> Settings >> Project Settings >> Gradle...
Under Global Gradle Settings, I set Gradle VM options to  *-Dhttp.proxyHost=www.somehost.org -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080*

I cannot post screenshots since I'm also new here at StackOverflow.

Kindly help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem starting out; this is what worked for me:

When I set the proxy in the regular menu it appears not to have set the https properties, only http properties. I ended up adding the https properties myself by editing the gradle.properties file (literally as simple as copying the 4 lines beginning with `systemProp.http.proxy` and adding an "s" to to get `systemProp.https.proxy`).

The file would look like this:

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=[PASSWORD]
systemProp.http.proxyHost=[IP ADDRESS]
systemProp.http.proxyPort=[PORT]
systemProp.http.proxyUser=[USERNAME]
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=[PASSWORD]
systemProp.https.proxyHost=[IP ADDRESS]
systemProp.https.proxyPort=[PORT]
systemProp.https.proxyUser=[USERNAME]
```