# Gradle cannot resolve dependencies when Building an Android Studio project

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

I am used to Eclipse and recently tried to import and build a project in Android Studio using Gradle. For some reason, it is not downloading the dependencies.

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
> Could not resolve com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1.
 Required by:
     nxt-freemarket-lite:app:unspecified
  > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/dagger/dagger/1.2.1/dagger-1.2.1.pom'.
     > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused
> Could not resolve com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.1.
 Required by:
     nxt-freemarket-lite:app:unspecified
  > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jakewharton/butterknife/5.1.1/butterknife-5.1.1.pom'.
     > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused
> Could not resolve com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1.
 Required by:
     nxt-freemarket-lite:app:unspecified
  > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/dagger/dagger-compiler/1.2.1/dagger-compiler-1.2.1.pom'.
     > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused
```

I can download all the .pom files in my browser. I have tried running Android Studio as Administrator, and disabled my Windows Firewall. Why can't it get these deps?

Comment: As the error suggests, you are having problems getting to JCenter at the moment. Either try again later, or figure out why you cannot get to that server, or consider adding `mavenCentral()` to the `repositories` closure as an alternative source for these dependencies and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Adding mavenCentral() alongside jcenter() does not solve the problem for me.

Comment: Do you access the internet via a proxy?

Comment: see and try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443208/androidstudio-gradle-proxy