# Why is retrofit failing in this code?

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit

I have a `php` server with a username(jonik) and password a (123456) in it as the login. I'm trying to login in with my app with retrofit but it always goes to the failure method. The server must respond "Success" to me if the connection happens, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong - Is it something in my code?

`mainactivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String myLoginEmailAddress = getLoginEmailAddress();
    TextView loginInformation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.login_email);
    if(myLoginEmailAddress != null || !myLoginEmailAddress.equals("")){
        loginInformation.setText("Welcome!!! You have logged in as " + myLoginEmailAddress);
    }else {
        loginInformation.setText("Your login email is missing");
    }
}

private String getLoginEmailAddress(){
    String storedEmail = "";
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle mBundle = mIntent.getExtras();
    if(mBundle != null){
        storedEmail = mBundle.getString("EMAIL");
    }
    return storedEmail;
  }
}
```

`loginactivity`

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final String TAG = "LoginActivity";

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://555.555.555.555";

// UI references.
private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private View mProgressView;
private View mLoginFormView;
private TextView failedLoginMessage;

View focusView = null;
private String username;
private String password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    // Set up the login form.
    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    populateAutoComplete();

    failedLoginMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.failed_login);

    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            failedLoginMessage.setText("");
            attemptLogin();
        }
    });


    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
}

private void attemptRegistration(){
    boolean mCancel = this.loginValidation();
    if (mCancel) {
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        registrationProcessWithRetrofit(username, password);
    }
}

private void attemptLogin(){
    boolean mCancel = this.loginValidation();
    if (mCancel) {
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        loginProcessWithRetrofit(username, password);
    }
}

private boolean loginValidation() {
    // Reset errors.
    mEmailView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    username = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;

    // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid username address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    } /*else if (!isEmailValid(username)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }*/
    return cancel;
}

private void populateAutoComplete(){
    String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.autocomplete);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countries);
    mEmailView.setAdapter(adapter);
}



private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
    //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
    return password.length() > 4;
}

/**
 * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        });
    } else {
        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

private ApiInterface getInterfaceService() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    final ApiInterface mInterfaceService = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    return mInterfaceService;
}

private void loginProcessWithRetrofit(final String username, String password){

    ApiInterface mApiService = this.getInterfaceService();
    Call<Login> mService = mApiService.authenticate(username, password);
    mService.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {

            Login mLoginObject = response.body();
            String returnedResponse = mLoginObject.isLogin;
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Returned " + returnedResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //showProgress(false);
            if(returnedResponse.trim().equals("success")){
                // redirect to Main Activity page
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                loginIntent.putExtra("EMAIL", username);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            }
            if(returnedResponse.trim().equals("error")){
                // use the registration button to register
                failedLoginMessage.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.registration_message));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
            call.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please check your network connection and internet permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Login

```
public class Login {
public String isLogin;
          }
```

`ApiInterface`

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/cult_tickets/request/login.php")
Call<Login> authenticate(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);
```

**EDIT**
i get this in the log but still in the login activity goes to failure

```
D/CustomLogRetrofit: <-- 200 OK       http://555.555.555.555/cult_tickets/request/login.php (298ms)
  D/CustomLogRetrofit: Date: Fri, 02 Dec 2016 05:27:47 GMT
  D/CustomLogRetrofit: Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h   PHP/5.6.24
  D/CustomLogRetrofit: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.24
  D/CustomLogRetrofit: Content-Length: 7
  D/CustomLogRetrofit: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
  D/CustomLogRetrofit: Connection: Keep-Alive
  D/CustomLogRetrofit: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  D/CustomLogRetrofit: success
  D/CustomLogRetrofit: <-- END HTTP (7-byte body)
```

Comment: what does your throwable says in onFailure ?

Comment: i get this toast  "Please check your network connection and internet permission

Comment: of course i wrote internet permission in manifest

Comment: try this video on youtube.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oiFfJrMcM4o

Comment: yes I understand, but there is a throwable object in that method. add t.printStackTrace(); there and read from log what is the purpose of exception

Comment: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps

Step 1- Check permission in menifeist file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Step 2- Check for Proxy setting (if there is proxy in your network) for that check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18443524/4741746

Step 3- Try to check response from postman or restClient is API working properly

Step 4 - **Change** public static final String BASE_URL = "http://555.555.555.555"; to your  **Orignal IP addresss  or LOCALHOST**

show us your manifest  file

Comment: 1-check
2- not proxy problem
3-it is working in postman
4-of course i changed my ip

Answer (score 0):

and that is your answer :) your java object is not convertable to server response. Basicly your Login object is not what coming back from server

add http loggin interceptor to your retrofit and you will se your responses :)

```
private ApiInterface getInterfaceService() {
      HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger myLogger = new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
        @Override
        public void log(String message) {
            Log.d("CustomLogRetrofit", message);
        }
    };
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(myLogger);
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client =  new OkHttpClient.Builder() 
                        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                        .build();



    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    final ApiInterface mInterfaceService = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    return mInterfaceService;
}
```

EDIT:
It is because your server is not returning JSON object. "succes" is just a String. You can either change your server to return something like `{"isLogin"="success"}` or use @Rainmaker solution (use RespondBody)

Comment: sorry you need to add to gradle compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0"

Comment: message -> Log.d("CustomLogRetrofit", message); what about this error ? and i did added it

Comment: I have changed it already. It was lamda expresion. Look at sushant gosavi response, and change BASE_URL as well

Comment: i'm getting my response in the message but in the login method jumps to failure method

Comment: i get my response in the log but not inside the loginmethod still jumps to faliure method

Comment: post your response from serwer and Login class

Comment: check my edit i wrote my log and still have this error after end http W/System.err: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: what should i write inside response body class ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Call<JsonObject> authenticate(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);
```

If you gonna get JsonObject

or

```
Call<ResponseBody> authenticate(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);
```

If you gonna get String

Comment: if i do this i will change my whole login method

Comment: Otherwise your server should return exact object that you android app expects.

Comment: yes i want the server to return success word like they build
i getting it with the new code that @wojciech_maciejewski give it to me but not entering inside login method

Comment: Watch logs in android studio. There must be a server response. Presumably it returns a wrong response.

Comment: no it returns right response but like i said it jumps to failure method

Comment: response body what should i write inside it