# Emulator: emulator: WARNING: Could not connect to proxy at ::1:8080: Unknown error ! - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy, android-emulator

> Emulator: emulator: WARNING: Could not connect to proxy at ::1:8080: Unknown error ! - Android

I am getting this error after updating `Android Studio 2.3.2` to `Android Studio 3.0 canary 2`. Because of this error Internet not working in the emulator.

**Edit**

I am using Android Studio on Windows 7 over LAN connection.

**UPDATE**
Though, It is not the solution but I downgraded the Android Studio to 2.3.3 and uninstalled the android emulator and reinstalled again. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly give more details ..like what type of connection you are using or what is your os. If you are on a proxy network try changing the settings in File -> Settings-> HTTP proxy. If that doesn't work look here

[AndroidStudio gradle proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443208/androidstudio-gradle-proxy)
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3aaccessing_the_web_via_a_proxy

> Configuring an HTTP or HTTPS proxy (for downloading dependencies, for example) is done via standard JVM system properties. These properties can be set directly in the build script; for example, setting the HTTP proxy host would be done with System.setProperty('http.proxyHost', 'www.somehost.org'). Alternatively, the properties can be specified in a gradle.properties file, either in the build's root directory or in the Gradle home directory.
>
> **Example 12.2. Configuring an HTTP proxy**
>
> *gradle.properties*
>
> ```
> systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
> systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
> systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
> systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
> systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
> ```
>
> There are separate settings for HTTPS.
>
> **Example 12.3. Configuring an HTTPS proxy**
>
> *gradle.properties*
>
> ```
> systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
> systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
> systemProp.https.proxyUser=userid
> systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
> systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
> ```