# Android Studio 3.0.1: Emulator: emulator: WARNING: Could not connect to proxy at :: Unknown error

Tags: android

I am getting this warning every time i launch apk on the emulator, and the apk crashes and gets closed. It seems to be trying to connect to proxy even though i am not sitting behind one. I tried disabling the proxy in File -> Settings -> Proxy and also ensured disabled proxy in the emulator in Extended Control -> Settings -> proxy, but still getting the same warning.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44495574/emulator-emulator-warning-could-not-connect-to-proxy-at-18080-unknown-err), but no solution. I also tried googling, but some suggestions prompted to switch to earlier version of SDK which i refused.

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 on Windows 10, 64 bit Intel machine.

Can anybody help me on this?