# Android Studio 0.8.2 "Gradle project sync failed."

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization

I'm completely new to android studio. Installed it plus all the skd packages the installation guide told me to. I've been trying a couple of things for the past two weeks now with no success. Can someone direct me to a solution or where more detailed error messages are found?

Im receiving this error message from the "Messages Gradle Sync" Panel:
"Error:(1, 0) Cause: com.google.common.collect.Sets"

edit : I have ubuntu installed on this computer aswell and I decided to install android studio on it. Its woking there so I guess I'll work from it until studio gets a fix or I find one.

Comment: I described method to get it working here, on Stack: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33690567/2672951

Answer (score 3):

1. Uncheck "Offline work" in File>Settings>Gradle>Global Gradle Settings
2. Resync the project, for example by restarting the Android Studio.
3. Once synced, you can check the option again to work offline
4. Update java if Android L SDK installed

Comment: The "offline work" box was already unchecked and I don't have the android L sdk installed

Comment: give android studio a direct internet connection after this once .

Answer (score 2):

-File -> Invalidate caches / Restart

-Shutdown Android Studio

-Rename/remove .gradle folder in the user home directory

-Restart Android Studio let it download all the Gradle stuff it needs

-Gradle build success !

Answer (score 2):

Open your project where its located

For example:

```
MyApplication->gradle->wrapper->gradle-wrapper.properties
```

go into it and change this row:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip
```

with this:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

and try to sync with this button [image]    in your IDE

Answer (score 1):

At https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71725 I found this answer by (#3 alinmit...@gmail.com) and it solved that problem for me.

In Android Studio go to File>Settings>Gradle>Global Gradle Settings and in Gradle VM options specify the proxy details:
-Dhttp.proxyHost=dummyHost -Dhttp.proxyPort=dummyPort -Dhttp.proxyUser=dummyUser -Dhttp.proxyPassword=dummyPassword

Answer (score 0):

I have Avast antivirus, i closed it and then the problem disappeared! try to disable your firewall and let us know! :-)

Comment: I have avast too so I thought this would work. I disabled all the avast real time shields and then disabled windows firewall. Is this what you mean? becasue I'm still getting the same error.